# How to slice DataFrame in python and make row that are separeted from DataFrame in the form of list

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I am new to python.
I have a Dataframe with 105120 rows and 33 columns shown below:

```
          n1     n4    n31    n54   n105   n114   n163   n188  ...   n636   n644   n679   n722   n726   n740   n752   n769
0       28.92  33.87  37.13  37.13  50.52  53.99  52.56  55.32  ...  45.53  47.62  47.33  46.14  47.12  43.81  49.17  48.50   
1       28.94  33.89  37.16  37.23  50.60  54.09  52.67  55.42  ...  45.61  47.71  47.39  46.19  47.17  43.83  49.22  48.54   
2       28.96  33.91  37.18  37.21  50.57  54.05  52.64  55.39  ...  45.61  47.71  47.41  46.20  47.19  43.84  49.24  48.56   
3       28.98  33.93  37.19  37.27  50.60  54.08  52.70  55.45  ...  45.65  47.75  47.43  46.21  47.21  43.84  49.26  48.57   
4       28.98  33.93  37.19  37.14  50.53  54.00  52.57  55.32  ...  45.54  47.64  47.34  46.15  47.13  43.81  49.17  48.50   
...       ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...  ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...   
105115  28.55  33.61  36.93  36.88  50.42  53.88  52.34  55.09  ...  45.34  47.40  47.12  45.98  46.90  43.73  48.94  48.33   
105116  28.56  33.61  36.94  36.82  50.38  53.82  52.28  55.03  ...  45.31  47.37  47.11  45.97  46.89  43.72  48.93  48.33   
105117  28.58  33.64  36.96  36.90  50.43  53.88  52.35  55.11  ...  45.36  47.44  47.16  46.01  46.95  43.74  48.98  48.36   
105118  28.58  33.64  36.96  36.85  50.40  53.86  52.31  55.06  ...  45.31  47.37  47.10  45.97  46.89  43.73  48.93  48.32   
105119  28.63  33.68  36.99  37.00  50.49  53.96  52.45  55.20  ...  45.44  47.51  47.22  46.06  47.01  43.77  49.05  48.42   

[105120 rows x 33 columns]
```

I want to separate each row from the Dataframe and each row will be represented in the form of list.
For example, the first row separated from the Dataframe would be represensted as follow:

```
[28.92, 33.87, 37.13, 37.13, 50.52, 53.99, 52.56, 55.32, 39.09, 52.53, 52.81, 42.45, 56.43, 46.75, 31.07, 45.62, 36.79, 43.52, 47.54, 51.7,  53.54, 54.85, 47.58, 54.8,  56.16, 45.53, 47.62, 47.33, 46.14, 47.12, 43.81, 49.17, 48.5]
```

And then each row represented in the form of list will be used to compare with the first row ( finding the difference between elements at the same position in each row and the first row).

Could you please tell how to achieve those two things?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: And what is the expected output?

Comment: It seems counterproductive to convert the dataframe row to a list to then go back to try to compare individual elements against corresponding elements. As corralien asks, what is your expected output? If you want a dataframe of differences (same number of columns and one less row), you'll probably be better off sticking with dataframes the whole time.
That said, `df.iloc[n].to_list()` will turn the nth row into a list.

Comment: Why do you want to change these to lists? You can simply do `df-df.iloc[0]`

Comment: Deleted my post as I think I've misunderstood the question. I thought differences in terms of which values are different than those in the same position in first row. Definitely follow @not_speshal advice.

Comment: if each row would be compared with a list that is not the row in the DataFrame. How should do it? thank you very much again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input data:

```
>>> df
       0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9
0  72.76  47.54  57.37  40.03  75.24  46.05  51.76  33.94  56.97  78.77
1  52.54  79.47  42.52  31.36  40.38  47.65  34.89  57.98  40.27  59.65
2  72.61  48.26  35.68  43.54  32.07  60.47  71.90  85.41  40.66  48.70
3  62.56  72.92  50.90  38.44  48.64  47.35  69.55  65.00  30.74  63.12
4  27.59  45.57  55.75  66.59  60.69  60.99  49.23  45.16  33.03  29.38
```

Difference between the first row and other ones:

```
>>> df - df.iloc[0]
       0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9
0   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00
1 -20.22  31.93 -14.85  -8.67 -34.86   1.60 -16.87  24.04 -16.70 -19.12
2  -0.15   0.72 -21.69   3.51 -43.17  14.42  20.14  51.47 -16.31 -30.07
3 -10.20  25.38  -6.47  -1.59 -26.60   1.30  17.79  31.06 -26.23 -15.65
4 -45.17  -1.97  -1.62  26.56 -14.55  14.94  -2.53  11.22 -23.94 -49.39
```

Convert to a list:

```
>>> df.values.tolist()
[[72.76, 47.54, 57.37, 40.03, 75.24, 46.05, 51.76, 33.94, 56.97, 78.77],
 [52.54, 79.47, 42.52, 31.36, 40.38, 47.65, 34.89, 57.98, 40.27, 59.65],
 [72.61, 48.26, 35.68, 43.54, 32.07, 60.47, 71.9, 85.41, 40.66, 48.7],
 [62.56, 72.92, 50.9, 38.44, 48.64, 47.35, 69.55, 65.0, 30.74, 63.12],
 [27.59, 45.57, 55.75, 66.59, 60.69, 60.99, 49.23, 45.16, 33.03, 29.38]]
```

Difference as a list: `df.sub(df.iloc[0]).values.tolist()`

**Update**

> if each row would be compared with a list that is not the row in the DataFrame. How should do it?

```
l = [55.89, 43.93, 32.39, 28.36, 39.98, 66.26, 51.56, 48.34, 37.33, 60.15]
```

```
>>> df - l
       0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9
0  16.87   3.61  24.98  11.67  35.26 -20.21   0.20 -14.40  19.64  18.62
1  -3.35  35.54  10.13   3.00   0.40 -18.61 -16.67   9.64   2.94  -0.50
2  16.72   4.33   3.29  15.18  -7.91  -5.79  20.34  37.07   3.33 -11.45
3   6.67  28.99  18.51  10.08   8.66 -18.91  17.99  16.66  -6.59   2.97
4 -28.30   1.64  23.36  38.23  20.71  -5.27  -2.33  -3.18  -4.30 -30.77
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. One more question, if each row would be compared with a list that is not the row in the DataFrame. How should do it? thank you very much again!